# variable value used by more then one shared library

Tags: c, linux, global-variables, shared-libraries

I am writing an application in C which uses both user defined satically linked library(using -l option) and dynamically linked library that i preload(using ld-preload). Now I have a variable (a socket connection) that is set up from the statically linked library and the same client socket is to be used by the other shared libraries too.

How do i declare and maintain the value this client socket across libraries till the connection is exclusively broken from the calling process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done this but seems like putting:

```
extern int yourfileno;
```

into the header file for the static library should work.
Declare this global variable in one of the c files for the same library.

Really this is the same as creating get/set routines in the library.

Some might consider it better practice to have the static library declare a struct definition:

```
typedef struct {
        int fileno;
        int is_opened;
        ...other stuf;
} StatLibType;
```

Then have you main program call something like:

```
StatLibType *statlib_new_connection();
```

Pass the newly created structure to the other dynaimic library so that it can use it.

Comment: @Bob...How do I pass the created structure to the dynamic library as the dynamic library is basically a wrapper around few Glibc functions like open(),Write()...etc

Comment: @juggler - You can have the dynamic library include a header file that is common with the static library where only the typedef exists and nothing else.  This creates a minor dependency between the two libraries which may be undesirable.  If you would prefer to keep the two libraries totally independent, then you could let the main program hold the structure and pass primitive values from the structure into the dynamic library.